# Get Firestore parent doc ID in subcollection

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is it possible to retrieve the parent document ID within a sub-collection?

The user can create a bot, which will itself contain a history linked to this bot.
To list this history against the bot ID., i need to be able to get the ID of the parent (that of the bot's document).

[image]

The minimal logic in cloud functions:

```
try {
  await db.collection("bots").add({
    createdBy: uid,
    createdAt: new Date(),
  });

  // create orders_history subcollection 
  await db.collection("bots").doc().collection("order_history").add({
    createdBy: uid, // user uid
    botId: context.ref.parent, // how i can get parent doc ID (7aIvUIjC...) ?
  })
} catch (e) {
  ...
}
```

My security rule should also check if `botId` is equal to the id of the parent document (7aIvUIjC....).

```
match /{path=**}/order_history/{id} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null id == resource.data.botId;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you realize that calling `db.collection("bots").doc()` generates a new random document ID that's different than the one you created previously with `db.collection("bots").add()`.  That doesn't really make sense to me - seems like you'd want to use the same ID both times if the order history is to be linked to the document added with `add()`.

Comment: BTW this has nothing to do with Cloud Functions.  You are just working with the Firestore backend API, and it behaves the same in any node environment, so I'm removing it from the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first post.

This sub-collection may contain hundreds of documents, the ID of the documents in this sub-collection must therefore be unique.

What I'm looking to do is link the documents in this sub-collection to the parent document (/bot/{id}).

The "Bots" collection can contain hundreds of bots.

A bot contains orders_history, and this sub-collection can contain hundreds of unique documents.

So the goal is indeed to retrieve the ID of the parent document, but I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the second snippet in the documentation on [adding a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js_5), you can see that it logs the ID of the new document:

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
const res = await db.collection('cities').add({
  name: 'Tokyo',
  country: 'Japan'
});

console.log('Added document with ID: ', res.id);
```

You can use the same logic, using the return value from the call to `add`, to get the ID that is needed for your subcollection:

```
const res = await db.collection("bots").add({
  createdBy: uid,
  createdAt: new Date(),
});

// create orders_history subcollection 
await db.collection("bots").doc(res.id).collection("order_history").add({
  createdBy: uid, // user uid
  botId: context.ref.parent, // how i can get parent doc ID (7aIvUIjC...) ?
})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, the security rules do not work. How can I retrieve the parent document ID in my subcollection?

On this part, the "id" should be the ID of the main document of the Bots collection :
id == resource.data.botId;

Comment: That seems like a different question, so I recommend creating a separate post for it.